# Sort and Remove performance in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm writing a program which determines whether an Array would be in strictly increasing order if one and only one element were removed. It works but apparently it does not pass the time limit set by codefights (To be clear it runs instantly on my local machine and on their servers fails the 30 second time limit (with 5000 numbers in the array)).

Which operation is the most performance consuming? Sort is only run once, the only operations that are run every iteration are patching the array, removing by value which is defined by array diff and distinct. Thanks.

```
def remove(num: Int, array: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = array diff Array(num)

def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence: Array[Int]): Boolean = {
    var i = 0
    val sortedSequence = sequence.sortWith(_ < _)
    while (i < sequence.length) {
        val patchedSequence = sequence.patch(i, Nil, 1)
        if(patchedSequence.sameElements(remove(sequence(i), sortedSequence).distinct)) return true
        i += 1
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. For an ordered array to be "strictly increasing" it must have no duplicates. If you're allowed to remove only one element then the the array must have no more than one duplicate. So wouldn't this be all you need? `sequence.diff(sequence.distinct).length<2` (I'm not sure how preformant it is, but it is certainly much simpler.)

Comment: No so order matters. For example the array (3,2,1) should return false even though there are no duplicates since no matter which element you remove the array will not be increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the trick with these things is *usually* avoid sorting (if possible) and traverse only once. Maybe something like this.

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence: Array[Int]): Boolean = {
  sequence.indices.tail.filter(x => sequence(x-1) >= sequence(x)) match {
    case Seq(x) => x == 1 ||                       //remove sequence.head
                   sequence(x-2) < sequence(x) ||  //remove sequence(x-1)
                   !sequence.isDefinedAt(x+1) ||   //remove sequence.last
                   sequence(x-1) < sequence(x+1)   //remove sequence(x)
    case Seq() => true  //no dips in sequence
    case _ => false     //too many dips in sequence
  }
}
```